# Why is mysqli_fetch_row preventing all my results from displaying?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a survey tracking website and I'm having trouble. I want to display all surveys that have been completed in the last 7 days. I'm using mysqli_fetch_row to see if any rows are retrieved, and if they are display them. If they aren't any compelted in the last 7 days, I want it to display the words "no recently compelted surveys to show."

```
<?php
            require('db/connect.php');
            if (!isset($_GET['sort'])) {
                $sort = 'client_id';
            } else {
                $sort = $_GET['sort'];
            }
            if ($result = $db->query("SELECT client_id, date_added, client, email, date_sent, date_completed FROM clients NATURAL JOIN surveys WHERE date_completed BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE() ORDER BY $sort")) {//shows surveys completed in the last 7 days
                if (mysqli_fetch_row($result) == 0) {
                    echo "No recently completed surveys to show.";
                } else {
                    echo "<table>";
                    echo "<tr><th><a href='portal.php?sort=client_id'>ID</a></th><th><a href='portal.php?sort=date_added'>Date Added</a></th><th><a href='portal.php?sort=client'>Client</a></th><th><a href='portal.php?sort=email'>Email</a></th><th><a href='portal.php?sort=date_sent'>Sent</a></th><th><a href='portal.php?sort=date_completed'>Completed</a></th>";
                        $rows = $result->num_rows;
                        for ($num = 0; $num < $rows; ++$num) {
                            $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
                                $client_id = $row[0];
                                $date = $row[1];
                                $client = $row[2];
                                $email = $row[3];
                                $sent = $row[4];
                                $completed = $row[5];
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>$client_id</td>";
                                echo "<td>$date</td>";
                                echo "<td>$client</td>";
                                echo "<td>$email</td>";
                                echo "<td>$sent</td>";
                                echo "<td><a href='survey/completed/index.php?id=$client_id'>$completed</a></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            echo "</table>";
                        } 
                    }
        ?>
```

When I remove the if clause for mysqli_fetch_row, it displays ALL of the recently completed surveys, but if I leave it in, it ALWAYS leaves one out. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why are you mixing *procedural* with *object oriented style*, ie. `mysqli_fetch_row()`, `$result->fetch_array()`?

Comment: `if (mysqli_fetch_row($result) == 0) {` Fetches the first row, and then you're discarding that result

Comment: @MarkBaker any idea how to fix it? i thought i was seeing if 0 results were returned, and if they are, print a message, and if not, display the data.

Comment: @Marcus I'm still learning, and I appreciate the input. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are discarding the first when you do the test. You can get the number of rows like this instead:

```
if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
    echo "No recently completed surveys to show.";
} else {
   // ....
}
```

Docs : [mysqli_result::$num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: Thank you sir. That did it.